# Is there a way to redirect the stdin to the "type" command in windows terminal(cmd.exe)?

Tags: windows, terminal, cmd, redirect

The desired result is the type command showing on the screen what I type on the terminal.

Comment: Please explain what makes this a programming question and on topic.

Comment: This will work: type CON

Comment: TYPE is used to display the contents of a file... Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type con
```

it can also be redirected to a file

```
type con >text.txt
```